# Websockets potentially interfering with Travis-CI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, travis-ci

I've googled around but haven't been able to find any specific issues related to my question. That lack of issues makes me believe it's an issue with my specific build.

I recently added socket.io to a side-project just to experiment with websockets a bit. Prior to adding socket.io my Travis build would pass no problem; however, post-sockets my Travis build will walk through the motions and display passing tests only to hang until the 10-minute timeout.

I'm using Node and React. The testing command I'm running is `"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"` The testing suite is just basic smoke-testing for components and some content checking. I can share the testing suite if needed, but as the tests all show as passing within Travis I didn't think it necessary to share.

What would be causing my Travis build to hang? So far as I could find in my research, unless you're testing the sockets directly they shouldn't be interfering with Travis. I haven't added any testing for the sockets yet or any components that use them.

Here's my **server.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const passport = require('passport')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const changeCat = require("./utils/randomCat");
const routes = require("./routes");
const authCheckMiddleware = require("./server/middleware/auth-check");
const FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token');
let config;
if(process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  config = process.env
} else {
  config = require("./config/index");
}

const app = express();

//...server logic...//

const server = app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(` ==> Server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});

let user = {
  userCount: 0,
  activeUsers: 0
};
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
  user.userCount++;
  socket.emit("broadcast", user);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    user.userCount--;
    user.activeUsers--;
    socket.emit("broadcast", user);
  });

  socket.on("deactivateUser", () => {
    user.activeUsers--
    socket.emit("broadcast", user);
  });

  socket.on("activateUser", () => {
    user.activeUsers = user.userCount
    socket.emit("broadcast", user);
  });

  setInterval(() => socket.emit("broadcast", user),1000);

  socket.on("error", err => {
    console.log(`Received error from user: ${socket.id}`);
    console.log(err);
  });

  socket.on('connect_failed', err => {
    console.log(err)
    console.log("connect failed")
  });
});
```

Finally, my **.travis.yml**:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "stable"

before_script: 
  - cd client
  - npm install

script:
  - npm run test
```

Quick rundown on project:
It's basically a quiz app that runs a quiz every 5 minutes with a different category each time.

edited @1:25P to edit title